# Speech to text converter in .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to make speech to text convertor application in C#.In this site i found number of threads but did not provide me the code to develop. I found a post [here](http://gotspeech.net/blogs/michaeldunn/archive/2007/02/28/vista-sapi-5-3-speech-recognition.aspx). But did not get how to add `.grxml` file as there is not such item present for selecting it. Also how it can be achieved. Any sample code or demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is best article provided for converting speech to text. Please refer http://ellismis.com/2012/03/17/converting-or-transcribing-audio-to-text-using-c-and-net-system-speech/
Hope this helps you.